# In Bluetooth Low Energy, why are Enhanced Data Rate packets only 3 Mb/s?

Tags: modulation, theory

In the "Introduction tu Bluetooth Device Testing" document ( https://download.ni.com/evaluation/rf/intro_to_bluetooth_test.pdf ), the modulations for Bluetooth Classic are said to be a Binary GFSK at 1 Msymbol/s, a pi/4-DQPSK at 2Msymbol/s, and a 8DPSK at 3Msymbol/s. But the phy data rates for the packets are said to be 1 Mb/s, 2Mb/s and 3Mb/s.

Given that a binary GFSK symbol corresponds to 1 bit, a pi/4-DQPSK symbol corresponds to 2 bits, and a 8DPSK symbol corresponds to 3 bits, I believe the number of symbol per second could be 1Msymbol/s to obtain the aforementioned phy data rates for the packets.

Is that an error in the document or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it's an error in the document. The Bluetooth Core spec v5.3 states that for BR / EDR, "The symbol rate for all modulation modes is 1 Msym/s" (p. 419).